# How to start Apache Ignite Client Node?

Tags: ignite

I am wondering if it's possible to start an Apache Ignite client Node by passing configuration parameters to the JVM. For instance, we may start a server Node by running "org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup" and passing config parameters to it.

I know it's possible to start a Node from inside a class implementation by initializing Ignite interface and explicitly joining a Cluster.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to start a client node is invoke the `Ignition.start(..)` method. For more details you can refer to any example shipped with Ignite and to this documentation page: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/clients-vs-servers

Comment: I am aware of this option, but that's not what I wanted. For instance Oracle Coherence allows to start  Node by passing Cluster and Cache configuration parameters to the JVM. Is there such an option in Ignite?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "passing Cluster and Cache configuration parameters to the JVM"? Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure. In Coherence I can pass "-Dtangosol.coherence.override" property to the JVM which essentially tells my particular JVM to join a Cluster and become either a client or server node. I don't need to code anything at this time. I am wondering if Ignite provides  something similar to that.

Comment: What is the purpose of a client node that is not running within an application? I'm not sure about Coherence, but I doubt that it makes any sense in context of Ignite. To start a standalone server node you can use `ignite.sh|bat` script providing an XML configuration file as a parameter.

Comment: I can think of at least one situation where I would prefer to start a client node in advance. I would rather know in advance that my client was not able to join a Cluster than at runtime. Of course, ignite.sh works perfectly fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper java class of your own which will take JVM params and then call org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup or any client api required to start the ignite client.

`public void main(String[] args) {

String property = System.getProperty("property");

}`
pass the xml file or properties received to System.getProperty("name")
using org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup